Word moves equations when translating
I want to translate a document from German to English with MS Word 2021 on Windows 11 (64). This works fine.
However, I have problems with equations, which are in the middle of a sentence. Word moves the equations after the sentence. Example of the output of the translation:

Gravity creates for closed orbits.E_rot<0

In the original text, the equation was after the "for". The formula is properly displayed.
Is there a way to avoid the shift of the equations behind the sentence, without rewriting the text?

Edit:
The orginal German text is:
Die Gravitation erzeugt für E_rot<0 geschlossene Umlaufbahnen.
Please note, that E_rot<0 is an inline forrmula:

That's how it look likes in the translation window. Please note the strange punctuation marks:


Is this an automated translation?  What package are you using to do the translation?

I use the built-in translation of MS Word 2021, which inserts the translation in place.

Could you post the original German text in the question?  When I try it on Word 2021, it appears in the right place.  It must be some punctuation that is confusing the translator.

Yes, you are right. Some strange punctuation marks appear in the translation window.

When I paste your text, there is a full stop before the E.  This causes the formula to translate properly.  Without it, the formula appears in the wrong place.  German word order can be Subect Object Verb (SVO) or SOV.  It must be taking the formula as the object and converting German SOV to English SVO.

If I translate: "Die Gravitation erzeugt geschlossene Umlaufbahnen für E_rot<0.", it turns out wrong. There is a full stop before the E.
